Django Summernote plugin upload image by userid
I am using the Summernote plugin for Django and my target is to allow users to upload media inside the server. At the moment files are organized (by default) in a folder named with the upload date. Something like:

"ProjectName/media/django-summernote/2024-10-11/989d2f98-ad3c-47d6-9c07-e5f6d0c731e6.png"
"ProjectName/media/django-summernote/2024-10-17/13d646b8-d7cd-4e04-a76a-804a1ee0d090.jpg".

Is it possible to change the path and include the user_id in the path?
Something like

"ProjectName/media/django-summernote/User100/989d2f98-ad3c-47d6-9c07-e5f6d0c731e6.png"
"ProjectName/media/django-summernote/User200/13d646b8-d7cd-4e04-a76a-804a1ee0d090.jpg".

What I have done
I made these edits in the settings.py file
# Summernote plugin
def summernote_upload_to(request, filename):
 user = request.user
    
    # Create the dynamic path
 upload_path = f'user_upload/{user}'
    return os.path.join(upload_path)

SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'attachment_upload_to': summernote_upload_to,
    'summernote': {
        'attachment_filesize_limit': 200 * 1000 * 1000, # specify the file size
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '480',
 }
}

but, when I upload an image, I get an error

AttributeError: 'Attachment' object has no attribute 'user'


where from did you get from that argument is request, it is instance, it is just wrapper around https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

I changed the function definition to '''def summernote_upload_to(instance, filename):
return "user_{0}/{1}".format(instance.user.id, filename)''' but I am still getting the same error.

Who downvoted my question could, please give us some details about this?

I understand you want to customize Summernote's upload path to include the user ID instead of the date. The error occurs because the attachment_upload_to function receives different parameters than what you're expecting. Let me help you fix this.
This are steps you can follow to solve problem
1.Creates a custom attachment model that includes user information
2.Modifies the upload path to include the user ID
3.Ensures the user information is available during file upload
4.Maintains the UUID-based filename for uniqueness
5.Provides a fallback for anonymous uploads
The files will now be saved in paths like:
ProjectName/media/django-summernote/User100/uuid-filename.png
ProjectName/media/django-summernote/User200/uuid-filename.jpg
Remember to handle any existing files and migrations carefully if you're implementing this in a project that already has uploaded files.
if need any code snippet ,reach me; I will provide detailed code but I assure that above code will works ,cause its work for my domain !

Hi Jeet, I can't see any code in your answer so I can't find any good value in it...I suggest you to improve the answer.
